# Hiding images based on PHP output

Tags: php, html

So I want to create an image that starts in a state based on a PHP function, and when clicked changes state.

I have not found any way to get the return value from a function in PHP to HTML. If I can do this, my problem is solved.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['button1'])){toggle();}
function toggle()
{
$filename = "brightness";
$otherDirectory="/sys/class/leds/led0/";
$f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"r"); 
$value = fgets($f);
$newvalue = 1;
fclose($f);
if ((int)$value == 1) {
   $newvalue = 0;
}

if ((int)$value == 0) {
   $newvalue = 1;
}

    $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"w+"); 

fwrite($f, $newvalue);

fclose($f);
}
function getLampState(){
$filename = "brightness";
$otherDirectory="/sys/class/leds/led0/";
$f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"r"); 
$value = fgets($f);
return $value;
}
?>

<html><body>
<img src="lightbulb_1.png" onClick='location.href="?button1"'/>
</body></html>
```

Don't mind the toggle() function, I'm done with that. I have 2 files (lightbulb_1 and lightbulb_0). If getLampState() returns 1, I want to show lightbulb_1, vice versa.

Any advice?

Comment: You must do an ajax call: see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ for simple example

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery...

```
$.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "phpScript.php",
    success:function(data){
    if(data==0)
        $("#imgTagId").attr("src","lightbulb1.png");
    else
        $("#imgTagId").attr("src","lightbulb2.png");
    }
});
```

In your php script simply "echo" whatever you wish to return.

If you're interested in including JQuery simply include the following anywhere in the head of your HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would go in the onClick handler of your HTML. AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) can be done in pure javascript but using a standard library like JQuery will make your life easier.

Comment: Wait, the onClick? Don't you mean the src?

Comment: This code chunk changes the src but should be executed whenever the image is clicked.

Comment: Hm, I still don't understand. Do I just put it after `onClick='location.href="?button1"'/>` or do I replace that? I suck at web development, sorry :/

Comment: Separate your HTML file from your php file. Set the onclick of your image tag to execute a block of javascript code which includes the above ajax call to you php script. Your script should "echo 0" or "echo 1" depending on the image you want to be displayed.

Comment: Bleh. Still having trouble. Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/NaheiH3r Sorry 'bout the spaghetti-ness of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
index.html

<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
function doThings(){
    $.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "script.php",
    success:function(data){
    //here whatever the script echos is inside "data"
    if(data==0)
        $("#imgId").attr("src","lightbulb_0.png"); //use # to select elements by id
    else
        $("#imgId").attr("src","lightbulb_1.png");
    }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- don't begin id's with numbers -->
<img id="imgId" src="lightbulb_0.png" onClick='doThings();'/>
</body>
</html>

script.php

<?php
//if(isset($_GET['button1'])){toggle();}
toggle();
function toggle()
{
        $filename = "brightness";
        $otherDirectory="/sys/class/leds/led0/";
        $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"r");
        $value = fgets($f);
        $newvalue = 1;
        fclose($f);
        if ((int)$value == 1) {
           $newvalue = 0;
        }

        if ((int)$value == 0) {
           $newvalue = 1;
        }

        $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"w+");

        fwrite($f, $newvalue);

        fclose($f);

        //this is what the html gets back (inside "data")
        echo $newvalue;

}
//what's this function?
function getLampState(){
        $filename = "brightness";
        $otherDirectory="/sys/class/leds/led0/";
        $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"r");
        $value = fgets($f);
        $filename = "lightbulb_";
        $fileending = ".png";
        echo $value;

}
?>
```

Does this work?

Comment: Hm. Partially. The onClick doesn't work, and it the image is always lightbulb_0.

Comment: Seems as if the ajax function doesn't change the lightbulb state.

Comment: No wait, I don't think the onClick does anything at all. Time to debug :/

Comment: Opps. Add an opening <script> tag before the javascript.

Comment: As in, at the onClick? Because the main javascript already has script tag.

Comment: Immediately before "function doThings(){".

Comment: Uh, OK. But what about the `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">` part?

Comment: It didn't work. Any other advice? You've been very helpful so far :)